# any rails command not doing anything freezing up/hanging up(rvm related?)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rvm

I was recently trying to debugg a few things and was copying and pasting a bunch of commands and I think one of them did something to my RVM or installed rbnv by accident.

Now when I am trying to anything like run the console it just stays frozen and doesnt do anything no matter how long I wait. When I exit the process I see the following output:

```
$ rails c
^C/Users/c5227806/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/client/run.rb:98:in `gets': Interrupt
    from /Users/c5227806/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/client/run.rb:98:in `verify_server_version'
    from /Users/c5227806/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/client/run.rb:56:in `run'
    from /Users/c5227806/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/client/run.rb:37:in `warm_run'
    from /Users/c5227806/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/client/run.rb:26:in `call'
    from /Users/c5227806/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    from /Users/c5227806/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:24:in `call'
    from /Users/c5227806/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    from /Users/c5227806/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/client.rb:26:in `run'
    from /Users/c5227806/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-1.3.6/bin/spring:48:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/c5227806/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
    from /Users/c5227806/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/c5227806/Desktop/dev_projects/rails_projects/sciencevest/bin/spring:13:in `require'
    from /Users/c5227806/Desktop/dev_projects/rails_projects/sciencevest/bin/spring:13:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:3:in `load'
```

I have been using RVM so not sure what is happening since I am not an expert on these things.

When I do:

```
$ rvm --version
rvm 1.26.11 (latest) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]
```

When I do:

```
$ rbenv local
-bash: rbenv: command not found
```

Maybe I am missing something or maybe the problem is something completely different. What is happening?

Answer (score 2):

I ran this: `spring stop` and now everything seems fine. Not sure what happened.